# a practical interview: one point about sessions

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, session

On a e-commerce website, there would be millions of users, how can we handle (optimize) sessions for all of them. I am thinking that we have a timeout added for each session, so optimization seems unnecessary. But this turns out not-quite-true. I would love to learn why and how we answer this simple question. Thank you

Comment: To maintain n number of session is server's headache.

Comment: Hi there, I am not killing myself, don't use this against me.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal LOL that was hilarious!

Comment: Define `optimize`. Storage space required, access speed, security - what do you want to improve? `But this turns out not-quite-true` - how did it turn out that way? Who told you this? *Why* did they say it's not quite true? With "millions" of users you are probably looking at DB-driven sessions, which introduces a whole bunch of other problems as well.

Comment: You may find a read of this quite interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500561.aspx - it's how Microsoft define load(scaling) issues and how you could tackle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are stored in FileSystem so actually unless your app requires lot of burn-out scratch on your harddrive, sessions are OK.

3 possibilities:

1. RAMDISK - Perfect alternative on windows. Disk on versatile RAM. No consequences except that your memory freeup has to be good in your application.
2. COOKIES - Y bother sessions when you can store information on client's machine? Sanitize cookies well.
3. Database - You can store information in "temporary" databases instead of session. However, this would be an alternative and not answer to the question so, I will stop right here.

Sessions are like coins with 2 sides.

Comment: I love your second point, I missed it once asked, I defensed why MS uses cookies instead of sessions and I was taught but didn't remember. I learn today, I forget tomorrow, I am no sad, I am happy to realize that I am a human being :-D. I am telling you that I understand about humans very much, and life much much more. I am fun little boastful `boy` :D

Comment: Nice to meet you! Such is the same with me ;) but, people call me a day-dreamer (which I mentioned even in my profile) :-D